# Error while publishing the Page using SDL Web 8 and DXA Search module

Tags: dxa, web8, si4t, dxa-1.5

I working on SDL WEB 8.1.1 and using DXA Search module 1.5, I have followed the steps mentioned in [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E241F065-1CDC-439B-BDF0-689F6C63BE32&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E241F065-1CDC-439B-BDF0-689F6C63BE32.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E241F065-1CDC-439B-BDF0-689F6C63BE32), but when publishing the Page, I'm getting the below error;

> Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed. Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-7187-66560. Error creating bean with name 'JPASearchBinaryContentDAO' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/SDL/Web/deployer/lib/si4t.jar!/com/tridion/storage/si4t/dao/JPASearchBinaryContentDAO.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchBinaryContentDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Indexable file extensions are not configured.

**Updated logs Image**
[image]

**Also deployer** `cd_storage_conf.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="8.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
  <Global>
    <Storages>
      <StorageBindings>
        <Bundle src="SearchDAOBundle.xml" />
      </StorageBindings>
      <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory">
        <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
        <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
          <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost" />
          <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
          <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
          <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
          <Property Name="password" Value="*******" />
        </DataSource>
        <Indexer Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer" DefaultCoreUrl="http://localhost:8984/solr/staging" Mode="http" DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt" />
      </Storage>

      <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
        <Root Path="D:\Websites\DXA\Site" />
      </Storage>
    </Storages>
  </Global>
  <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
    <!-- <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile" /> -->
    <!-- <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/> -->
  </ItemTypes>
  <License Location="D:\Web 8.1.1\Web 8 Developer License\cd_licenses.xml" />
  <ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://111.111.1.1:8082/discovery.svc" ConnectionTimeout="40000" CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY=">
    <Roles>
      <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://111.111.1.1:8084/httpupload">
        <Property Name="undo.enabled" Value="false" />
        <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8" />
      </Role>
    </Roles>
  </ConfigRepository>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: How does your deployer's `cd_storage_conf.xml` look? Did you use the Search Module's `deployer-install.ps1` ?

Comment: @RickPannekoek .. After executing the `deployer-install.ps1` the error got change i have attached the error log image and deployer's `cd_storage_conf.xml` .. Pls suggest

Comment: Are you sure you are using 8.1.1? The spurious error "Unable to configure **filesystem** storage provider with id **defaultdb**" is the kind of error you would get on 8.1.0 without hotfix applied.  Also note that the `Storage Type="Filesystem"` should not be used, so that element should be removed to avoid confusion.

Comment: @RickPannekoek .yes we are using SDL Web 8.1.1 release

Comment: See first line of your `cd_storage_conf` it is referring to `Configuration Version` `8.0` and hence trying to validate with that version of xsd , maybe you upgraded to 8.1 and missed some steps.